# No HDMI audio output on Radeon 7700 series

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, 20.04

I've spent weeks trying to figure out why I can't get HDMI audio to work.
I know the hardware works, because when I boot from a live DVD, it works fine (speaker test of 5.1 channels).

I've googled and tried everything on sound troubleshooting, alsa remove and reinstall, delete pulse folder, etc.
I've even upgraded to 20.04 beta, but this didn't fix it either.

I have a Radeon 7700 series video card.
I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!